# R: Labels in ggarrange for ggplot won't work

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I expect this to be an easy fix, however, I spent quite some time researching related posts on this topic but didn't really come close to solving my problem.

I have this 3x2 ggarrange object where I want a label in every row. So far so good, but I don't want the labels to be "A", "B" etc...rather I am evaluating a Questionnaire, so I want the label to be more like a headline for every panel of rows.

I tried positioning them with options like vjust = or hjust = but could not make it work properly.

What is my approach? There are several options I am sure. I have also tried using the cowplot and the patchwork packages but I always get stuck at the same thing.

I use the mtcars package for some example code:

```
p1 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
p2 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp)) + geom_point()
p3 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = cyl)) + geom_point()
p4 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = drat)) + geom_point()
p5 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = drat, y = wt)) + geom_point()
p6 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec)) + geom_point()

pcars1 <- ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ncol = 2, nrow = 3,
                   common.legend = T, legend = "bottom",
                   labels = c("A", "", "B", "","C",""))

pcars2 <- ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,p5,p6, ncol = 2, nrow = 3,
                    common.legend = T, legend = "bottom",
                    labels = c("This is example A", "", 
                               "This is example B", "",
                               "This is example C",""))

note <- "Notes: This is mtcars data. A: Test sample 1, B: Test sample 2, C: Test sample3."

annotate_figure(pcars1, top = text_grob("Figure 1: Nonsense plots with mtcars"),
                bottom = text_grob(note, x = .5, size = 9))

annotate_figure(pcars2, top = text_grob("Figure 1: Nonsense plots with mtcars"),
                bottom = text_grob(note, x = .5, size = 9))
```

So the object pcars2 is what I want. Only it's supposed to be on the left and above the first plot of each row and not right in the plot. Possibly also with a smaller font and not bold but I'll fix that later.

Any help is massively appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `patchwork` and especially `patchwork::wrap_elements` you could do:

```
library(patchwork)

note <- "Notes: This is mtcars data. A: Test sample 1, B: Test sample 2, C: Test sample3."
title <- "Figure 1: Nonsense plots with mtcars"

list(
  p1 + p2 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example A"),
  p3 + p4 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example B"),
  p5 + p6 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example C")  
) |> 
  lapply(wrap_elements) |> 
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1) +
  plot_annotation(title = title, caption = note) &
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

[image]

**EDIT** The default way to add a legend to a `patch` would be to use `guides="collect"`. However, as my approach used `wrap_elements` (which is the trick to have a title for each row) that option is not available (except for the case where we want a separate legend for each row). So we have to it the hacky way, which for example means to first extract the legend for one of the plots using `cowplot::get_legend`. Second, remove the legends when glueing the plots together. Finally add the legend as part of the patch and set the `heights` argument to your liking.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(magrittr)

p1 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = cyl, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p2 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = disp, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p3 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = cyl, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p4 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = drat, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p5 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = drat, y = wt, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()
p6 <- mtcars %>% ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = qsec, color = factor(cyl))) + geom_point()

library(patchwork)

note <- "Notes: This is mtcars data. A: Test sample 1, B: Test sample 2, C: Test sample3."
title <- "Figure 1: Nonsense plots with mtcars"

legend <- cowplot::get_legend(p1 + theme(legend.position = "bottom"))

plot_list <- list(
  p1 + p2 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example A") & theme(legend.position = "none"),
  p3 + p4 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example B") & theme(legend.position = "none"),
  p5 + p6 & plot_annotation(title = "This is example C") & theme(legend.position = "none")  
) |> 
  lapply(wrap_elements)

c(plot_list, list(legend)) |> 
  wrap_plots(ncol = 1, heights = c(rep(10, 3), 1)) &
  plot_annotation(title = title, caption = note) &
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = .5))
```

[image]

Comment: One question though, since I cant claim to fully understand this yet as I have no experience with patchwork. I should have written this in advance but I do want to have a legend. Now I have a legend next to each plot, but I would need a common legend on the bottom. &(theme(legend.position = "bottom")) does nothing so far. Then again I understand why it doesnt do anything since I dont understand the syntax of your patchwork code

Comment: Adding a legend is a bit hacky. But see my edit for one approach.